# How to mimic a sequence in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

In an application I have to generate numbers that can never be repeated, just like a sequence. So, each time a user asks for a number, the application has to return the last value generated plus one, **never repeating a value**.

A sequence would work perfectly, except for the fact that each new day the generating seed has to be reset to 1 again. So, today the application starts generating numbers from 1 and no matter what is the last generated value, tomorrow it will generate values **starting from 1 again**.

How to accomplish that?

Comment: Is there a `date` or `timestamp` column in the row?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: yes, it does!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html) for this. No need to mimic it.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_serial START 1;
```

Then select values by

```
SELECT nextval('my_serial');
```

Then at mid night you [alter the sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altersequence.html).

```
ALTER SEQUENCE my_serial RESTART WITH 1;
```

The reset can be a cron job or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a SERIAL column.

Something along those lines.

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
id SERIAL,
MY_COLUMN varchar);

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (MY_COLUMN) values ('ROW1');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (MY_COLUMN) values ('ROW2');

SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE;

1,ROW1
2,ROW2
```

[datatypes SERIAL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)

To reset a SERIAL column to 1 every day you would need to run a (cron ?!?) job with something like

```
SELECT SETVAL((SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('MY_TABLE', 'id')), 1, false);
```

If you’re using a SERIAL field, PostgreSQL will actually create a SEQUENCE for you, which increments every time you insert a row. In order to reset it, you need to know what the sequence name is. It is usually something like

[table_name]_[serial_field_name]_seq

You can find the sequence name by running the pg_get_serial_sequence('[table_name]', '[serial_field_name]').

Comment: What about reseting to 1 each day? A SERIAL is just a shortcut for a SEQUENCE, it does not really respond to my needs, because I have to restart from 1 each day.

Comment: @AlexSC have a look at my updated answer. That said, I had a man look at your question and the Serial column might not be the ideal solution. e4c5 answer might suit you better... :)

Comment: `serial` **is** using (and creating) a sequence. The only difference is that with a `serial` the sequence is dropped when the column is dropped which uses it.

Comment: sporting of you to recommend my answer

Comment: @e4c5 Everybody wins with better answers for the questions. :)